# Couldn't found geoname_id for North America in Geolite-city.csv / Geolite-country.csv

Tags: geoip, maxmind, geolite2

We are using `GeoLite2-City.mmdb` for parsing IP addresses. After parsing IP address "8.8.8.8", the result was:

```
{"continent":{"code":"NA","names":{"de":"Nordamerika","ru":"Северная Америка","pt-BR":"América do Norte","ja":"北アメリカ","en":"North America","fr":"Amérique du Nord","zh-CN":"北美洲","es":"Norteamérica"},
"geoname_id":6255149}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find this continent by `geoname_id`, was searching in:
1) GeoLite2-Country-Locations-en.csv
2) GeoLite2-City-Locations-en.csv

All files were recently downloaded. So there is could be a lack of data in `csv` file compare to `mmdb`?

Answer (score 0):

On the csv from 2020/01/14, I got for 8.8.8.8 `geoname_id` = 6252001, which is (according to GeoLite2-Country-Locations-en.csv):

`6252001,en,NA,"North America",US,"United States",0`